# How to use customer HTML/CSS in class SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint

Good Day All,

I created a custom page using HTML/CSS/JS and when testing everything works smoothly in the browser. The problem is how can I load this into a SharePoint (Classic) page?

I have the JS inside the HTML file and when I load just HTML page with the basic js it renders fine in SharePoint and works fine, just isn't styled.

However, when I load in the CSS, SharePoint goes bonkers and the sidebar and topbar/editing buttons all go crazy and become messed up. I then have to delete the html file from the SharePoint library to get the SharePoint page back to normal.

I thought maybe the CSS was attempting to be applied to whole page so I got rid of any generic css stylings like "table" "div' etc. and switched all css to classes and ids to avoid any unwanted applications but it still breaks the page.

I have never had to load code into a SharePoint page before so I am not sure if it's possible or what the best practices are.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should post your code here. It is difficult to say anything without seeing the code

Comment: Are you trying to upload a HTML page, or a script to SharePoint

Comment: Hi, I am using web parts then media parts to link in an html file into the SharePoint. Once the CSS is applied the page breaks. I have tried posting the html directly to the content editor and linking to the CSS file and also tried putting the CSS in the html file and linking to the SharePoint. Anytime the CSS is linked the page breaks.